# How do I make a view refresh when the value changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an app that displays the number of steps on the screen. However, when the view that displays the steps is initialised, the number of steps doesn't change unless the user restarts the app. To solve this I tried to use @ObservableObject & @Pubslihed but haven't been able to achieve the results I wanted.

Here is the class:

```
class HealthStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    @Published var query: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
            
        }
    }

    func calculateSteps(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsCollection?)-> Void) {
        
        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
        
        let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
        
        let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                    [.init(format: "metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered), predicate]

                                )
        query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(
           quantityType: stepType,
           quantitySamplePredicate: compoundPredicate,
           options: .cumulativeSum,
           anchorDate: anchorDate,
           intervalComponents: daily)
        
        
        
        
        
        
        query!.initialResultsHandler = { query, statisticsCollection, error in
            completion(statisticsCollection)
            
        }
        
        if let healthStore = healthStore, let query = self.query {
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false) }
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [stepType]) { (success, error) in
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the onLoad function that makes the steps data appear on the view (not using onAppear because it duplicated the view every time the view was initialised): This is used on a view.

```
.onLoad {
            if let healthStore = healthStore {
                healthStore.requestAuthorization { success in
                    if success {
                        healthStore.calculateSteps { statisticsCollection in
                            if let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection {
                                // update the UI
                                updateUIFromStatistics(statisticsCollection)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for the onLoad function:

```
struct ViewDidLoadModifier: ViewModifier {

    @State private var didLoad = false
    private let action: (() -> Void)?

    init(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            if didLoad == false {
                didLoad = true
                action?()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func onLoad(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        modifier(ViewDidLoadModifier(perform: action))
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to get the values to refresh in the view when they change?

Comment: "Make a View Refresh" is always the wrong question when it comes to SwiftUI. Ask, how does "X Service" provide updates (identifying the process and type) what SwiftUI wrapper is compatible with the type. Your code is not a minimal reproducible example so I would suggest you look at [Build a workout app for Apple Watch from wwdc21](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009) Apple goes over queries and listening to the HealthKit there.

Comment: Agree with the above -- learning the basics of SwiftUI (what `@State`, `@StateObject`, etc do) will be very helpful here. Check out the SwiftUI tutorials from Apple, Hacking with Swift, etc